# correct way to delete cookie when JWT token expires

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, jwt

i have jwt based authentication, and it works good for GET calls but it often causes connection errors like net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET, net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED and etc. after i perform POST request after token expires  so i researched it and understood that it is caused by cookies, so i checked browser and it has not deleted cookie includes expired jwt token but when i refreshed page server sent 401 HTTP code and redirected me to sign in page (it is good because it is my middleware's purpose)

so only thing i do now is, check if token does not exists i send 401 code and redirect user to sign-in page (it happens when unauthorized user tries to reach routes which is secured by this middleware), else jwt verifies that token and if there is error i check if error name s 'jwt expired' and if it is 
i send 401 status and clear cookie before that. otherwise i generate "req.userId", here is that code:

```
const guardr = (req, res, next) =>{
    const token = req.body.token ||
              req.query.token ||
              req.headers['x-access-token'] ||
              req.cookies.token;

if(!token){

    return res.status(401).send({redirect: true, location: '/sign-in'})
}  
else{
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET, function (err,decoded){
        if(err){
            if(err.message === 'jwt expired'){
                  res.clearCookie('token')
                  return res.status(401).send({redirect: true, location: '/sign-in'})               
            }


            console.log(err.message)
            return res.status(500).send({
                message: err.message
            })
        }

        req.userId = decoded.id;
        next()
       })
    }            
}
```

but as i said it mostly does not works properly with POST request, i say mostly because currently i am sending data with formdata with this code

```
 const data = new FormData();

data.append('image', this.fileRef.current.files[0]);
data.append('name', this.state.name);
...
```

and this code mostly return error above, but if i change files[0] to files, it does not return that error but file uploading does not work (once even token was disappeared (token cookie was empty)). in my server side i do not do anything complicated i just get variables sent with formdata and log them. but still if my multer configuration is important here is it

```
     const storage = multer.diskStorage({

destination: (req, file, callback) => {
 const userPath = path.join(imgStoragePath, req.userId);
 fs.mkdir(
  userPath,
  () => callback(null, userPath)
  )
},

filename: (req, file, callback) => {
const filenameParts = file.originalname.split('.');
const ext = filenameParts.pop();
const basename = filenameParts.join('.');
const additionalPath = Date.now() + '' + uuid() + '' + 
Math.floor(Math.random() * (2000 - 500)) + 500;
    callback(null, basename + '-' + additionalPath + '.' + ext);
  }

})

const upload = multer({
 storage,
 limits: '1mb',
 onError: function(err, next){
 next(err)
 }
})
```

and i send request with axios with this code

```
 axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: '/api/recipes',
      config: {headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }},
      data: data
 })
 .then(res => {
    console.log(res.data);
 })
 .catch(err => {
   if(err.response){
     if(err.response.data.redirect === true){
       window.location.replace(err.response.data.location)
     }
     if(err.response.data.message){
        alert(err.response.data.message)
     }
  }
});
```

so how can i delete cookie when token expires to prevent this errors, by setting exactly same expiration date as token? or what? THANKS!